# How to get text from imageview?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have added text in imageview. But I confuse to get text from it. **Because ImageView doesn't have method getText**. That's why I ask in here.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/char_3"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/char_6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/char_6"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/char_3"
    android:text="3" />
```

How to get text from imageView ??? What is method which used ??

Comment: you can,t get text from Imageview,to acheive this you have to take a textview below your imageview.

Comment: in your opinion, what would you expect ? which text should be returned from the image ?

Comment: You're right, thanks for your comment. I have found question about creating textview inside of imageview

Comment: @hans ID character. I hope after user click character, ID character is sent to database.

Comment: sorry, i still do not understand. the "id" is something you are using programmatically to identify an object.